Movie with a lot of double crossing and lies
Does anyone remember this movie with a ton of double crossing in it? There was sexual content.
There were two girls as the main characters, the nerdy girl turned out to be the mastermind in the end, but throughout the whole movie we were made to believe the nerdy girl was getting screwed over.
Her father fakes his own death with a plane crash, but at the end we figure out he's still alive and he and the nerdy girl try to flee with money or jewels or whatever it was and the nerdy girl fills his parachute with newspaper and lets him fall to his death. When she lands she meets up wit her mom, whom everyone thought was dead, and before the movie is over she looks at her moms cups as if it were drugged.
At the very least the movie is 10 years old.
The case or poster has a girl underwater except for her head and the reflection in the water is of another girl's face, which represents all the double crossing. 

The movie you're after is Wild Things 2.
Here is the poster, looking exactly as you described it:

And some plot details that match your description:

Brittney Havers (Susan Ward), a South Florida high school senior,
  lives with her wealthy stepfather, Niles Dunlap (Anthony John
  Denison), after her mother ran her car off the road in "Gator Alley"
  and was presumably eaten by alligators a year earlier. When Dunlap is
  killed in a private plane crash, his will calls for Brittney to
  receive a small stipend until she finishes college, after which she
  will receive only $25,000 a year for life from the estate.
Later, Brittney flies off in a private plane with the very much alive
  Dunlap, who had faked his own death to escape prosecution for
  misappropriating millions of dollars of corporate funds to pay his
  gambling debts, and also to avoid the Cuban gambler to whom he still
  owed millions.
It is revealed that Brittney and her mother orchestrated everything,
  including the deaths of Brittney's co-conspirators, in order to steal
  Dunlap's fortune, and they relax in the sun on a tropical island.
  Brittney comes down the stairs of their villa overlooking the ocean
  with two drinks and hands one to her mother. As Brittney watches intently, her mother takes a sip and remarks that the drink is strong. Brittney replies "They do make them strong here, don't they?" with a wry smile, the implication being that she has poisoned the drink.


Interestingly, I found this movie because the plot details described in the question made me think about the original Wild Things immediately. While checking the plot on Wikipedia I realised that it's not this movie, but I noticed that a sequel exists and it turned out that this was the one.

"she will receive only $25,000 a year for life" ONLY? GOD I WISH.

Oh my gosh!!! Thank you so much I feel like I can finally sleep at night. Not knowing the title has been killing me.
